# Getting type of object in R

Tags: r, object

Python has the `type` function which tells you if something is a list, numpy array or a string etc. That is, it tells you the class of the object. However, R seems to have just `typeof` and `class` functions that tell you what the *internal* data type is - say, it gives `double` when I do `typeof(array(1,2))`, and it gives list when I do `typeof(list(1,'a'))`. My questions are:

1. What exactly do typeof and class do? Why don't I get array and list above, or integer and integer/character? Moreover, where do these two methods differ?
2. What if I want to know what the type of object at hand is - i.e. is it a list? A matrix? An array (in the case above)? A string? Is there a way to do this other than doing something like referring to each specific one in a way such as `is.array` (not sure if that's a thing even)?

Comment: I may be completely off, but is it for S4 objects that they have a class attribute?

Comment: If you want to check for a class for an object `x`  `"myclass" %in% class(x)` is a good option because objects can have multiple classes.